# store sub arrays on different length in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

How do you store sub arrays of different length in C++?

I know you can store a sub arrays of fixed size length, by specifying the the number of elements in the `[]` brackets. For example here I specify the parent array will have 10 sub arrays, and each sub array will have 2 elements `units[10][2]`.

```
string units[10][2] = {
        {"0", "zero"},
        {"1", "one"},
        {"2", "two"},
        {"3", "three"},
        {"4", "four"},
        {"5", "five"},
        {"6", "six"},
        {"7", "seven"},
        {"8", "eight"},
        {"9", "nine"}
    };
```

But lets say for example I didn't know the size of the sub arrays, instead of 2, I have `x` number of elements in the subarray.

```
string units[][] = {
        {"0", "z", "e", "r", "o"},
        {"1", "o", "n", "e"},
        {"2", "t", "w", "o"},
        {"3", "t", "h", "r", "e", "e"},
        ...
    };
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: You present a 2D vector of `char`. Why not using a 1D vector of `std::string` ?

Comment: @Damien its a 2D array of strings

Comment: @idclev463035818 I know that `"z"` is officialy a string. But why using a string to hold one character?

Comment: @Damien a string that gets initialized with a single character can be resized later, a `char` can't. Anyhow its the type that matters not the contents

Comment: Wouldn't a `std::map` be even better if the first entry is actually a key: `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>`? Or even `std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>>` if the numeral isn't already stored as a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) comes in handy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> units = {
            {"0", "z", "e", "r", "o"},
            {"1", "o", "n", "e"},
            {"2", "t", "w", "o"},
            {"3", "t", "h", "r", "e", "e"},
        };

    // print result:
    for(auto& inner : units) {
        std::cout << "size " << inner.size() << ':';
        for(std::string& unit : inner) {
            std::cout << ' ' << unit;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
size 5: 0 z e r o 
size 4: 1 o n e 
size 4: 2 t w o 
size 6: 3 t h r e e
```